# Angular 10 : mat-elevation-z is not working for any component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular10

I'm using the class mat-elevation-z4 in a mat-toolbar e mat-card elements, and it simply doesn't work. Even if I don't apply any other CSS in those elements.

The versions:
Angular CLI: 10.0.6
Node: 10.14.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 10.0.9

The application is running in Chrome desktop, and I've tried in Firefox also.

I used this to try to fix: but it only worked in toolbar and generated other bugs:

```
.antiBug {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;    
}
```

My mat-card:

```
<mat-card class="mat-elevation-z4">
    <mat-card-title class="title">Bem vindo!</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle class="subtitle">
        Sistema para exemplificar a construção de um cadastro em Angular
    </mat-card-subtitle>
</mat-card>
```

I don't want to blindly install older versions of Angular in the hope that the problems disappears.

How can I fix this?

**PS: coincidentally, in the same project I have material buttons, and their styles are working, EXCEPT the mat-rised-button, which is "3D" to. It looks like Angular is having some problem to control z-index...**

Look at the class mat.elevation-z8  of my tool-bar

[image]

**And here, the same of my mat-card**

[image]

Comment: Elevations are in even numbers like 2,4,6...

Comment: @Eldar, so let me try with an even...

Comment: @Eldar, it's not the problem...

Comment: it does work [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z8tqtk?file=src/app/card-fancy-example.html) and its the easiest thing to track, its just CSS, can you inspect the element and see if your box-shadow is being overridden

Comment: I don't understand very well these browser tools. But I put the image above. Look at the class mat-elevatiion-z8, it is not scratched. It means that it was not overriden, right?

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem, but it turns out that when I did install the Angular Material, it does not added **"./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"** to my **angular.json** style section, inside the build section.

[Style section of the angular.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96E8G.png)

After adding this code, it's working fine!

Comment: Found the answer here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13003

Comment: it's already added in my angular.json and still does not work

Comment: @Tarik Waleed, I was trying to apply the `mat-elevation-z6` class to a `mat-card` element, and even though I had the reference in `angular.json` (which was auto added when I installed angular material) it still seemed not to be working. When I inspected the element in my browser, I noticed that chrome was reading styles from this class, but they were being overridden. So, maybe this class isn't possible to be used on certain elements? Either way, I ended up copying the style from the browser and creating my own class to force apply the style.